# Insert text conditionally using vim key mapping

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create a mapping which will add a yanked text to the end of the line, but additionally precede it with a space if the char at the end of the line isn't a space.

```
Base string: The quick brown fox 
                               ^no space, just fox$
Desired after pasting: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Base string: The quick brown fox 
                                ^additional space, fox $
Desired after pasting: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I'm not very experienced when it comes to writing functions in vim. Here is what I came with (not working properly):

```
nmap \p :if getline(".")[col("$"-1)]==" " <CR> $p <CR> :else <CR> :execute "normal! A \<C-R>\"" <CR> :endif <CR>
```

I wanted to check the last char in the line and paste the yanked text, or append a space and insert the " register (yanked text). This mapping however only shows me the commands in an expanded status line, and than moves me to the end of file.

How should this mapping look like?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know those fancy `:if` commands, but why not

```
:s/[^ ]$/& /e<CR>$p
```

First we do a substitution:

```
s/[^ ]$/& /e
```

This matches a non-space character (`[^ ]`) at the end of the line (`$`) and if such a character is found, replaces it with itself (`&` is the matched string in an `s///` command) followed by a space. If there is no match (the line doesn't end with a non-space character), the `s///` is a no-op. The `/e` flag prevents the "no match" condition from being an error, which would abort the macro.

The hard part done, we just go to the end of the line (normal-mode `$` command) and paste (normal-mode `p`).

Comment: could you comment the particular parts of this command please? Is & the whole match?

Comment: Any way to disable the hlsearch while performing this operation? So after the paste, the end of each line wouldn't be highlighted? Something other than performing another search of random characters this time after pasting?

Comment: I don't normally use highlighting, but it looks like adding a `:nohlsearch<CR>` to the end of the macro will do it. (Note: not the same as `:set nohlsearch` which turns it off permanently; `:nohlsearch` just turns off what is highlighted right now.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> \p :<C-u>execute 'normal! $"=(getline(".") =~# " $" ? "" : " ") . getreg(' . string(v:register) . ")\<lt>CR>p"<CR>
```

This doesn't clobber the last search pattern (as the solution from Wumpus Q. Wumbley), and you can even prepend a different register to paste (`"a\p`).

Comment: sounds like it's more universal than using regexps. Could you also comment on particular parts of the command? I get the big picture but I get confused in a few places.